# spring REST repository - modify returned response field

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have just started using Spring and hoping someone knowledgeable can help me out. I have a spring rest repository using spring rest data. I am trying to work out how to do the following.

1. Access the authenticated user when a request comes in and based on the users attributes, mask one of the repository response fields based on whether they have this attribute. For example, request comes in to get the list of data. But before we return the data, we check the user has "paid" for example and leave data as is or if they don't, change a response field to mask that content and replace the "content field value" with "..." for example. Can this be done using the standard repo or do I need to change to a controller and redo all the code? Example code below:

   public interface ReadOnlyRepository extends Repository {
       T findOne(ID id);

   ```
   Iterable<T> findAll();

   Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);

   Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
   ```

   }

   public interface ContentRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<...> {

   }

   // the field that I need to replace on the fly with '...'
   @Entity
   public class Content {

   ```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String content;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had setup the Spring SEcurity context, you can do like below in the getContent() method your Entity class

```
public String getContent(){

    Authentication auth = 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if( auth.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"))) {
    return content; 
    }else{
       return "...";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is roughly what I was looking for. The db field I need to use is from the users database table though, not a granted authority or scope. Basically I log the user in using oauth2 and they access the api with the token. Can the security context access the user using this token to authenticate and can I get acces to the user entity fields in the same way as you do for the granted authority?

Comment: Richard, write a simple Authentication filter in spring, process the token, match it with User in database and populate the Security context. This is the perfect use case. Security context is used to store the authentication details.